# PHP Regex to remove everything but the date from filename

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-replace

I have a filename with a date in it, the date is always at the end of the filename.
And there is no extension (because of the basename function i use).

What i have:

```
$file = '../file_2012-01-02.txt';
$file = basename('$file', '.txt');
$date = preg_replace('PATTERN', '', $file);
```

Im really not good at regex, so could someone help me with getting the date out of the filename.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "get the date out" do you mean remove or retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use preg_match instead of preg_replace:

```
$file = '../file_2012-01-02';
preg_match("/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/", $file, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // contains '2012-01-02'
```

Comment: This is actually what i was looking for, this way it doesnt matter what they put infront of the date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try:

```
$exploded = explode("_", $filename);
echo $exploded[1] . '<br />'; //prints out 2012-01-02.txt
$exploded_again = explode(".", $exploded[1]);
echo $exploded_again[0]; //prints out 2012-01-02
```

Shorten it:

```
$exploded = explode( "_" , str_replace( ".txt", "", $filename ) );
echo $exploded[1];
```

Comment: Ah great,  totally didn't think about this.
feel a bit stupid now :)


thank you very much.

Comment: Or `$date = end(explode('_', str_replace('.txt', '', $filename)));`

Answer (score 0):

If there is always an underscore before the date:

```
ltrim(strrchr($file, '_'), '_');
      ^^^^^^^ get the last underscore of the string and the rest of the string after it
^^^^^ remove the underscore
```

Answer (score 0):

With this, use regexp when you really need to :

```
current(explode('.', end(explode('_', $filename))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help i think:

```
<?php

$file = '../file_2012-01-02.txt';
$file = basename("$file", '.txt');
$date = preg_replace('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', '', $file);

echo $date; // will output: file_

?>
```